# How to delete a versioned S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-s3

The AWS Console won't let me delete a bucket it says is empty (and whose files I deleted using the console) because, when I click delete, it tells me the bucket isn't empty. I assume that this is because deleting the files didn't delete their earlier versions. Is this correct? If so, how can I clean out the bucket? This 2 cent charge on my credit card bill each month is getting annoying. =)

Comment: This is not a programming question — you might ask this on serverfault.com or superuser.com.

Comment: Well, I saw plenty of other similar questions here and suspect I might need to drop down and use the API directly, so...

Comment: I'd love to post a Java sample of how to do it, but... stackoverflow... sigh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Via the [AWS Forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=184564): use [Cloudberry](http://cloudberrylab.com/), or [BucketExplorer](http://www.bucketexplorer.com/).

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately BucketExplorer can't solve it, so I've taken it to the AWS forums: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=63943